# Symfony: Create DB User after LDAP Login

Tags: ldap, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.1.
I have an app with two firewalls. One for the normal DB-Users and one for LDAP-Users.
Where is the best place to create an DB-User, if a LDAP-User is successfully logged in? Should I do this over a Listener or over an UserChecker?
I need a DB-User for the handling inside the app.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: `AuthenticationSuccessLister` should be the best place to have an interaction with `EntityManager`